# ActionBar from Support Library and phone above Android 3.0

Tags: android

I understand that for Android below 3.0 i need to use ActionBar from v7 support lib
My question is how v7 ActionBar behaves on phones above Android 3.0. Does is use native ActionBar or v7 ActionBar?
I am asking if v7 ActionBar on phones with Android 3.0 and above will be of less quality
(may be less features) than regular ActionBar
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you decide to use `ActionBarCompat` - all your devices will get action bar from compat library. Of course you can have some really tricky API version checks and choose one over another in runtime, but efforts and code complexity just don't worth it. I wouldn't say it is going to be "less quality" since Google guys are really trying hard to make it look the same. Also Im pretty sure list of interfaces is exactly the same as native implementation.

From another hand, there is obviously a risk to hit some nasty bug which is not present (or already fixed) in native implementation, so it is all up to you to take this risk to the benefit of supporting older platforms.

Comment: Are you sure they do not switch to native inside v7 for android above 3.0? Where is the src code for ActionBarCompat?

Comment: yeap. <add more chars to let this comment pass 20 chars requirement>